# Get filename and size into an array

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get the filename and size into an array so i can compare them in a for statement:
I have the following code:

```
list=( $( ls -al *.gz |awk '{print $9, $5}' |grep 2014-08-12 ) )
for line in ${list[@]}
  do
    echo "0="${line[0]}
    echo "1="${line[1]}
done
```

But the result is:

```
0=2014-08-12.tar.gz
1=
0=50265
1=
0=2014-08-12.tar.gz
1=
0=693766
1=
```

Result should be:

```
0=2014-08-12.tar.gz
1=50265
0=2014-08-12.tar.gz
1=693766
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3):

You must avoid parsing `ls` output. To store file size and file names use `stat` command:

```
sizes=()
names=()
for i in *.gz; do
    sizes+=( $(stat -c "%s" "$i") )
    names+=( "$(stat -c "%n" "$i")" )
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `stat` with a `read` loop:

```
while read -r size file; do
    echo -e "0=$file\n1=$size"
done < <(stat -c "%s %n" *.gz)
```

Using Awk:

```
awk '{print "0="substr($0,index($0,$2))"\n1="$1}' < <(stat -c "%s %n" *.gz)
```

Comment: +1. In case the filename contains whitespace, you should use `stat -c "%s %n"` and read the size first.

Answer (score 0):

One proper way to iterate through your linear list is

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#list[@]}; i += 2 )); do
    echo "0=${line[i]}"
    echo "1=${line[i + 1]}"
done
```

Or simply

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#list[@]}; i += 2 )); do
    printf '0=%s\n1=%s\n' "${line[i]}" "${line[i + 1]}"
done
```